# WPF ListBox property binding not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, listbox

I have the following setup:

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Height="20" Width="20" Visibility="{Binding HasInformation, Converter={StaticResource VC}, ConverterParameter=True}" Source="/path/to/information.png" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

*Note: The ConverterParameter being passed in simply controls whether the visibility is "Collapsed" (`False`), or "Hidden" (`True`), so in this case, I want the visibility to be `Hidden`.*

**ViewModel Snippet:**

```
private ObservableCollection<IItem> _MyItems;
public ObservableCollection<IItem> MyItems
{
    get
    {
        return _MyItems;
    }
    set
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged(ref _MyItems, value, "MyItems");
    }
}

private IItem _SelectedItem;
public IItem SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return _SelectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged(ref _SelectedItem, value, "SelectedItem");
    }
}
```

**IItem:**

```
public interface IItem
{
    string Name { get; }
    bool HasInformation { get; set; }
}
```

I populate an implementation of a list of `IItem` from a database into the list, and the information icon appears appropriately if `HasInformation` is true. This all works correctly.

However, if I set `HasInformation` by hand, the view does not update. I have tried:

In the ViewModel:

```
OnPropertyChanged("MyItems");
MyItems[MyItems.IndexOf(SelectedItem)].HasInformation = true;
// Note that "SelectedItem" is persisted correctly, and always
// points to the selected item that we want to update.
```

In the code behind:

```
MyList.GetBindingExpression(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

All of these fire the getter of the `MyItems` property, **but the view never updates and the icon never displays.** I have ensured that the `HasInformation` property of the item that I updated does, in fact, remain `true`. I've attached to the `PropertyChanged` event to ensure that it's firing a property change for `"MyItems"` (it is, this also fires the getter), and I've even ensured that it's calling the value converter with the correct value for the `HasInformation` property (it is!), so what am I missing? Is there something weird with image showing/hiding or visibility value conversion that I'm not handling correctly?

Comment: Show where you implement HasInformation

Comment: Similar to @Blam, I suspect that the HasInformation implementation in the IItem interface does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  Just because you use an ObservableCollection does not mean that when a property in a contained item changes that the ListBox or other elements will get notified.  Just when the collection changes (add/remove items) will the listbox be notified.

Comment: +1. If your IItem implementation is being provided by your database then you have to use whatever mechanism your database code provides to allow you to inject property notification into the objects it creates (I personally use Castle Dynamic Proxy to do this with NHibernate). The alternative is to create a wrapper for each of your data models in the viewmodel and add that functionality yourself.

Comment: Why was I being downvoted? This is a legitimate question. :/

Comment: You were asked twice to show the implementation of HasInformation and did not.  And that was the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ObservableCollection only notifies the collection changes not the changes in each of the item. In order to achieve your goal one of options is to change the IItem from interface to a class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface (or implement it in the IItem concrete type), and hook it with the ViewModel's PropertyChanged delegate (remember to unsubscribe it). See some of my code below.

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _MyItems;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> MyItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyItems;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_MyItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in _MyItems)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged -= PropertyChanged;
                }
            }

            if (value != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in value)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged += PropertyChanged;
                }
            }

            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Item _SelectedItem;
    public Item SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _SelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Item**

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private bool _hasInformation;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool HasInformation
    {
        get { return _hasInformation; }
        set
        {
            _hasInformation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why forcing a binding update, or calling `OnPropertyChanged("MyItems");` doesn't work, though. Shouldn't that force the list to update?

Comment: Either way, this was the problem. I actually had the implementation of this interface in a Castle component/provider, and I was afraid to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` because I wasn't sure if that would be breaking the MVVM pattern or not. After I implemented it on both the interface contract and the actual implementation, it works great. Thanks.